# Limit sine problem: $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2}{2x+1}\sin\frac{\pi}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have this limit problem:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2}{2x+1}\sin\frac{\pi}{x}$$

I had tried to solve it but I think I am using the wrong approach. Can anyone help me? My steps:

[image: my attempt]

Comment: Let $y=1/x$, or maybe a little better let $t=\pi/x$, and it will soon be over.

Comment: The left limit is not $\infty$ but $-\infty$. So sandwich theorem cannot be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the [sine function satisfies the inequalities for $\pi\ge z \ge 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)

$$z\cos z\le \sin z\le z$$

Then, letting $z=\pi/x$ reveals

$$\frac{\pi \cos (\pi/x)}{x}\le \sin (\pi/x)\le \pi/x$$

Then, we have

$$\frac{\pi x \cos (\pi/x)}{2x+1} \le \frac{x^2}{2x+1}\sin(\pi/x)\le \frac{\pi x}{2x+1}$$

By the squeeze theorem, we obtain

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^2}{2x+1}\sin(\pi/x)=\pi/2$$

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.  I think I totally forget about that sine function satisfies the inequalities for z>0, may I know why? I think I need to read up on the basics again. Thank You!

Comment: Sorry I am confuse, may I also know why πcos(π/x)/x becomes πxcos(1/x)/2x+1. I understand that u multiply x^2/2x+1. but why did cos(π/x) becomes cos(1/x). Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.

Comment: As for the inequalities for the sine function, we can appeal to geometric arguments.  [SEE THIS](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)

Comment: Dr. MV, so can I assume that this inequalities is always true and use your approach to solve the question, whenever I see similar question? Thank You!

Comment: $\sin z\le z$ is true for $z\ge0$.  $\sin z\ge z\cos z$ is true for at least $0\le z\le \pi$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Our expression is equal to
$$\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}\cdot\frac{\sin(\pi/x)}{(\pi/x)}.$$

Comment: Thank You! May I get more explanation, I cannot figure out how to get your equation. I am sorry....

Comment: I first brought one  of the $x$ on top downstairs as $1/x$, getting $\frac{x}{2x+1}\frac{\sin(\pi/x)}{1/x}$. But I wanted a $\pi/x$ downstairs, which is easy, mutiply top and bottom by $\pi$. The motivation is that if we let $t=\pi/x$, we then have $\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}\frac{\sin t}{t}$. But it is standard that $\frac{\sin t}{t}\to 1$ as $t\to 0$. And the behaviour of $\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}$ for large $x$ is familiar.